# PHP - Remove Line Breaks From Textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv, line-breaks

I was wondering what I am missing in my code.  I have a large form that is pushing all values to a `.csv file`.  There are instances of `textareas` and every time I put some text content in and add a line break (hit the enter-key) within the `.csv` document, any line of text after the first breaks the flow of the values within the `.csv`, and starts a new line.

I've tried checking taking the value via php and removing any spaces or breaks, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="fianlCommentsText" name="fianlCommentsText"></textarea>
```

**PHP:**

```
$finalCommentsText = $_POST["finalCommentsText"];
function finalCommentsLineCheck()
    {
        global $finalCommentsText;
        preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $finalCommentsText );
    }
    finalCommentsLineCheck();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "choice" of \r or \n requires parens:

```
preg_replace( "/(\r|\n)/", "", $finalCommentsText );
```

Try that?

Comment: AH, dagnabbit, typo...fixing answer now.

Comment: the order should be **/  (   \r  |   \n   )   /**   i know it's hard to see the order...i just messed it up twice.  hahahaha

Comment: Trying it now! Don't worry, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Still not working!  I think something must be wrong with some section of my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126653/discussion-between-webjuju-and-theodore-steiner).

Answer (score 2):

In my case I solved in this way:

Output to a textarea removing the '\n' characters:

```
<!-- this textarea will show blank carriage return and not \n characters -->
<textarea  class="settinginput" id="message" name="message">
<?php echo str_replace('\n',"\n",$message); ?>
</textarea>
```

After submit here is how to replace the carriage returns with the '\n' not expanded characters:

```
str_replace("\r\n",'\n',$_POST['message'])
```

Note that the replace function uses double quotes and single quotes in order to save the string with no expansion for escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow multiline fields in csv, you need to quote them with `"`

For example:

```
12345,"multiline
text",another_field
```

In case you have quotes inside your text, just escape them with another quote:

```
12345,"27"" monitor 
TFT",another_field
```

This way you can keep the newlines inside the text.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not grasping what you're trying to explain.  It's an input so I won't have prior access as the user writes, but, do you mean the section where I am pushing my variables to the .cvs needs to be in quotes, like this? $csvData = $firstName . "," . $lastName . "," . "$homeAddress"

Comment: Yes, before writing the multiline field to the csv enclose it in double quotes - that way you can keep the newlines as entered by the user.

Comment: @theodoresteiner - what Danny_ds is suggesting is that you no longer remove the \r and \n, but instead, update your csv saving code to allow it to be saved.  you can have line breaks in your csv, you just have to properly "escape" them so that they don't break the csv.  you should have a look at http://php.net/fputcsv which will assist you with the escaping.